# How to limit current for this LED in circuit with a load?

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, diodes, boolean-algebra

I'm a newbie in electronics and just recently decided to get some deeper knowledge and try to start some projects. But it didn't take that long before I became stuck. Here's my problem.

I want to design a circuit with 12DC output that will be connected to two loads in parallel and each load would have its own signal LED diode. This diode will light up if everything works correctly and be off in case of a open circuit. I was thinking about using transistors or making some sort of a logic gate but I'm not sure how to continue: [image]
I came up with this diagram, R1 and R2 being the loads that use 10W (so there needs to be 14.5ohm resistance in the circuit, right?). But curcuitlab doesn't even think that's a valid circuit (neither do I, haha)

So could you please help me understand how to make that circuit work? Also that would be an option only for an open circuit, for a short circuit fault would something like a fuse be an appropriate solution? Thanks

Comment: That circuit will not work as you intend; it will simply burn out the transistors and/or the LEDs. Do you want to be able to switch the loads on and off separately?

Comment: Yes and also if one fails it doesn't stop the whole circuit. Also if one fails I would like to see via LED indication which one.

Comment: How do you want to control the loads?  A separate switch for each?  A signal from a microcontroller?  What are the loads, exactly?

Comment: For a somewhat similar circuit, place the LED on the collector then place a control resistor on the emitter. You can then adjust the LED current by varying the base voltage. Alternately you could leave out the transistor and just use a resistor inline with each LED.

Comment: If you put the LED and a current-limiting resistor in series with the *collector* instead of the emitter, this idea could work for small loads. However all of the load current would go through the transistor's base and that is very likely to overload and burn out the transistor in real life.

Comment: FYI, CircuitLab uses "." for a decimal point, not ",". That may be why you are getting errors. But after errors corrected, you still need current limiting resistors for the LEDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This circuit will light the respective LED when current is flowing through the respective 14.5Ω resistor, typically turning on about 1/2 of the expected current. In other words, if the resistors are less than about 28 ohms you can expect the LEDs to light when the switches are 'on'.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFVEOO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It uses a single 8-pin DIP integrated circuit dual op-amp. I don't think the circuit can be much simpler. You should connect a bypass capacitor of 100nF across and near the op-amp supply pins.

Vr is about 40mV and the resistors R1/R3 drop about 80mV when the switches are 'on'. R1 and R3 are low resistance so they waste very little heat and can be small parts.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to do this trying to keep the circuitry somewhat similar to what you started with. (Note: This is a revision to the initial circuit.)

As shown, each 14.5 ohm load will pass about 780 mA*.
This current will also flow through the small value sense resistor (R1, R4) producing enough voltage drop to turn on the PNP transistor. With the transistor on current flows through the LED. If the load resistance were open there would be no voltage drop on the sense resistor and the transistor would turn off and shut off the corresponding LED.

*This method is not so efficient, the load will see a slightly lower voltage and current. A small amount of voltage is actually lost on the sense resistors. You may be able to use a 0.82 ohm resistor for some small improvement. You might use this circuit example just as a starting point and improve it as needed. (A more complex op-amp design could improve this idea even further as it could work with an even lower value sense resistor.)
.

[image]

Comment: Which resistors represent the loads whose current is being measured?

Comment: @user253751 - OK, a bit of a circuit revision with load resistors clearly shown.

Comment: I see - the current through R_Load1 makes enough voltage drop across R1 to turn on Q1. The circuit could also be flipped upside-down and built with NPN transistors, if desired.

Answer (score 0):

What you show won't really do the job: the transistors will be full-on and the LEDs will vaporize in short order.

If your intention is to show that there is *current* flowing in each load, you'll need to devise a *current-sensing* circuit that will light the LEDs when on.

For overcurrent, you have few couple of options. One, use a current limiter circuit. Two, use a PTC fuse. Three, use an actual fuse (say, an automotive type.)